# Nodejs urlencode binary data

Tags: node.js, urlencode

Is there a way to use the Nodejs [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module to url encode binary data?

For example, the set of bytes **\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a**, once encoded is equivalent to **%124Vx%9a**.

I don't have a problem doing this in Python:

```py
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'q':b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a'})
'q=%124Vx%9A'
```

Trying this in Nodejs I get the wrong encoding as **%124Vx%EF%BF%BD**:

```
> u = new URL('http://www.google.com');
> qvar = Buffer('123456789a','hex')
<Buffer 12 34 56 78 9a>
> u.searchParams.set('q',qvar.toString('utf8'))
> u
URL {
  href: 'http://www.google.com/?q=%124Vx%EF%BF%BD',
  origin: 'http://www.google.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.google.com',
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '?q=%124Vx%EF%BF%BD',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'q' => '\u00124Vx�' },
  hash: ''
}
```

If I could pass in the byte buffer directly to *searchParams.set()* I am guessing I'd have more luck. The *URL* object expects strings for its parameters, so how can I convert raw hex to a string that it will properly quote?

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the value of `%124Vx%9A` from the buffer of `<Buffer 12 34 56 78 9a>` using Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, as one method, how about using a module of [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js)? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

At first, please install encoding.js as follows.

```
$ npm install encoding-japanese
```

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var Encoding = require('encoding-japanese');

u = new URL('http://www.google.com');
qvar = Buffer.from('123456789a','hex');
console.log(qvar);

var encoded = Encoding.urlEncode(qvar);
console.log(encoded);

u.searchParams.set('q', encoded);
console.log(u);
```

#### Result:

```
<Buffer 12 34 56 78 9a>
%124Vx%9A
URL {
  href: 'http://www.google.com/?q=%25124Vx%259A',
  origin: 'http://www.google.com',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'www.google.com',
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '?q=%25124Vx%259A',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'q' => '%124Vx%9A' },
  hash: ''
}
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to encode the value of `%` of `%124Vx%9A`, how about this?

  - `console.log('http://www.google.com?q=' + encoded)`

#### Reference:

- [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Nice, I like the encoding.js module but the problem remains with the URL module. You can see how encoding.js quoted the hex values correctly but the URL module then quoted that value to ?q=%25124Vx%259A. So the value got double quoted which doesn't work. I ended up doing what you placed in your note before I asked the question, but was still curious if I was missing something.

Comment: @fthinker Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my proposal was not what you want. Before I posted this, I had been looking for the method without URL encoding for the URL module. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the option and the other methods without modifying the URL module. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: Oh no apology necessary! If there isn't a way to use the URL module, then there isn't a way. I do appreciate your effort though.